# inserting unicode values in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I want to insert unicode text to mysql table, so for this I have written below code

I am using flask framework

```
import MySQLdb as ms
db = ms.connect("localhost","username","password","dbname")
cursor = db.cursor()

my_text = "का" #this is marathi lang word
enc = my_text.encode('utf-8')  #after encoding still it shows me marathi word
db_insert = "INSERT INTO TEXT(text) VALUES '{0}'"
cursor.execute(db_insert,(enc))
db.commit()
```

It gives me following error

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting on line cursor.execute()

How to remove this error ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but does your database support Unicode encoding?

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim how to check if db supports or not ?

Comment: For collation, type `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database;` To check the default character set type `SHOW CREATE TABLE table;`

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim charset `latin1`

Comment: Change the character set collation to `utf8_general_ci` or any other `utf8_*` value.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the beginning of the source code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And don't encode something that is already encoded - remove `my_text.encode('utf-8')`

Use `charset="utf8", use_unicode=True` in the connection call.

The `CHARACTER SET` in the table/column must be `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.  `latin1` will *not* work correctly.

[Python checklist](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a sequence (a `list` or `tuple`) to the `params` in `cursor.execute` statement:

```
db_insert = "INSERT INTO TEXT(text) VALUES (%s)"
# notice the comma at the end to convert it to tuple
cursor.execute(db_insert,(enc,))
```

You can read more in the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples):

> Why the `tuple`? Because the DB API requires you to pass in any parameters as a sequence.

---

Alternatively, you could even use [named parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html):

```
db_insert = "INSERT INTO TEXT(text) VALUES (%(my_text)s)"
#and then you can pass a dict with key and value
cursor.execute(db_insert, {'my_text': enc})
```

Comment: not all arguments converted during string formatting ... this error is thrown